# Script in Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to make a script in Google Sheets where I delete duplicates records.
The code should run based on the data in column A.

I am trying to use the below code but for some reason nothing is happening when i run the script.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length)
      .setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: The code you share runs on every column in a row, not just the content of column A. If there are no duplicates across the entire range of content, then no deletions will be done.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can you tell me what to change to only look at column 1?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that. I suggest you review the Apps Script Spreadsheet Service and familiarize yourself with the methods you use (`getDataRange()`, `getRange`, `setValues`), and also with the native JavaScript methods you use (`Array#join`, `Array#push`) so you can understand what your script is doing in each line.

Comment: I found the solution:function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
var firstColumn = sheet.getRange(1, 2, rows, 1).getValues();
firstColumn = firstColumn.map(function (e) {return e[0]})
  for (var i = rows; i >0; i--) {
    if (firstColumn.indexOf(firstColumn[i-1]) != i-1) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
    }
  }
}

Comment: If you think your solution will be useful to others, consider adding it as a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise consider deleting the question.